# Magento 2: Show/hide shipping method based on payment method selection

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, shipping-methods

I want to hide free shipping when purchase order payment is selected and then show free shipping when any other payment method is selected.

Comment: When the customer selects `Free Shipping` don't show the **Purchase Order** payment method. Is this work for You?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest method is to add a afterPlugin to the function `\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping::getAllowedMethods`

In this function, you will need to list the active payment methods.

`\Magento\Payment\Model\PaymentMethodList::getActiveList`

If the payment method you want to use to filter `free_shipping` is returned as part of the active payment methods, then you may remove `free_shipping` from the `getAllowedMethods` thanks to this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you are attempting to hide some payment options depending on the shipping method. You don't even need to pay attention to anything for this. Simply follow my lead and you can do this.

Every technique (in a single page check out) posts the strategies that are picked for the following phase. so that you can see the chosen shipping method at the level of the payment method. Print the post items in

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml
```

in this, add below code,

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

You can now obtain the shipping options you selected in the previous step. And take note of it so that you can directly add a straightforward logic (if else) condition to the same file to hide the payment.

For example, here I want to hide `check / money order` payment method if the shipping method is flat. Here the payment method code is `checkmo`. you can get payment method code by simply printing that variable like `echo  $_code = $_method->getCode();` in same file. so here just add simple if else ,

```
<?php
    $methods = $this->getMethods();


    $oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1;
?>
<?php if (empty($methods)): ?>
    <dt>
        <?php echo $this->__('No Payment Methods') ?>
    </dt>
<?php else:
    foreach ($methods as $_method):
       echo  $_code = $_method->getCode();


if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
if($_code == 'checkmo') {
    continue;
}
}
?>
```

Here,

```
if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
if($_code == 'checkmo') {
    continue;
}
}
```

checks the shipping method and skips the payment method which we don't want to display. That's it.

**Note:**

```
shipping_method => flatrate_flatrate
paymet_method   => checkmo
```